# How to find the residing directory of a OS X application package - programmatically

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a OS X application as a .app package which can reside in any
arbitrary location in the filesystem. Is there a way to find the
current path of the package programmatically from with.

## NOTE

getcwd() doesn't work since the current directory of all packages opened
is via click-open or using the open command is "/" . If i invoke the executable 
from myapp.app/Contents/MacOS , the directory is shown correctly.
It is a cocoa application.

Any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to find the location of the .app by `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];` or `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];`.

However, you probably want to access resources inside the .app by going through `NSBundle` to locate them in most cases (this deals with issues like localization).

**Note:** If you are planning to modify the application bundle; ***don't.*** You should not, can not and must not assume that you have write access to the application bundle; and if you do, something is likely very wrong.

**Edit:** As a point of interest, if you are writing a C program on OS X and need to find the location of the executable; you can use a non-portable main declaration like so:

```
int main (int argc, const char *argv[], const char *env[], const char *path[]) {
  // path[0] now contains the path to the executable
  // NOT PORTABLE! OS X ONLY!
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Deepak Narayan: I have to restate my two ancillary points: Don't assume that you can modify the application bundle, and access resources through `NSBundle`'s `-urlForResource:ofKind:` and friends.

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking to modify the bundle, i just need the directory path to change directory and load some files from the directory where the .app is.

Answer (score 2):

Building off the `argv[0]` version above, you can also get the path from:

```
    NSArray* arguments = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];

    NSString* exe = [args objectAtIndex:0];
```

from `init` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

Comment: You should strive to make your answers self-contained; other answers may be edited, deleted, or simply move around so that it's no longer "above" yours.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle directory might be a problem with command line tools. So i use the following function which uses the mach-0 linker function to resolve shared libraries.

```
 static char* find_executable_filepath () noexcept 
 {
     char path[1];
     uint32_t size = 1;
     if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) == 0) return nullptr;
     char* res = (char*)malloc(size+1);
     if (_NSGetExecutablePath(res, &size) != 0) return nullptr;
     char* r = realpath(res, nullptr);
     free(res);
     return r; 
 }
```