# How to install gems in a Ruby Mac OSX app without needing sudo access?

Tags: ruby, macos

I am trying to install gems in a Ruby Mac OSX app. I have:

export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/...

However this requires sudo access which I'm trying to avoid. Where do you install it so it installs inside the directory of the app? In the Resources folder or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Applications are usually expected not to modify their own bundle (their application directory). Unless you are planning to ship these gems as part of your app you should probably create a gem home for them in your application's "Application Support" directory.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH2-SW9

> The Application Support directory is where your app stores any type of file that supports the app but is not required for the app to run, such as document templates or configuration files. The files should be app-specific but should never store user data. This directory is located inside the Library directory.
>
> Never store files at the top level of this directory: Always put them in a subdirectory named for your app or company.
>
> If the resources apply to all users on the system, such as document templates, place them in /Library/Application Support. To get the path to this directory use the NSApplicationSupportDirectory search path key with the NSLocalDomainMask domain. If the resources are user-specific, such as workspace configuration files, place them in the current user’s ~/Library/Application Support directory. To get the path to this directory use the NSApplicationSupportDirectory search path key with the NSUserDomainMask domain.

Comment: If these gems are required for the app to function I would favor shipping them with the application. At the very least have clear failure cases if someone launches the app for the first time without access to rubygems or wherever you are pulling gems from.

Comment: Yeah they're required for the app to function. So would it then be: export GEM_HOME=Applications/Program/Program.app/ or is it further inside the folder in Resources or somewhere else?

Comment: I think they would need to at least be in your bundle's Contents directory in order for the app bundle to be valid. I think I would favor Contents/Gems but Contents/Resources/Gems might also make sense. Sorry I don't have a well justified opinion beyond that executable Ruby scripts don't seem like they should be mixed with app data in the Resources dir. There is probably a better informed opinion out there. Have you looked at how MacRuby apps are packaged?

Comment: Also make sure to avoid absolute paths. I should be able to use the app from /Applications, ~/Applications, ~/Desktop, or wherever else I want to place it.

Comment: So something like, ~/Contents/Resources? Or is there another way to get to the app directory no matter where it is?

Comment: `~` would be the user's home which isn't what you want. You want paths relative to the application's directory. Depending on how you invoke ruby that might be your default working directory, I'm not sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087328/how-to-find-the-residing-directory-of-a-os-x-application-package-programmatica and related questions should cover that.